# cropperjs > error in creating container

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, cropperjs

I'm building a chrome extention: https://github.com/justaguy84/resizemy.photos.chrome that will help crop and resize images from the web.
i'm using cropperjs libary: https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs 
For some reason, when changing crop size i'm getting 2 crop container instead of just one and both of them have some issue with their width / height.

What's strange is that it's working sometimes and sometimes doesn't while the only change is refresh of the page.

Hoping someone can help.
Thanks.

**UPDATED**

Here is the html and js code:
**html**

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Resize My Photos Test Page</title>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified cropper CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/cropper.min.css">

  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/general.css">

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">

      <div id="editor">

        <h1>Choose your image size</h1>

        <div id="custom" class="editor-section">
          <h2>Custom size</h2>
          <div id="custom-sizes">
            Width <input type="text" name="custom-width" id="dataWidth"> PX 
            <a class="link">
              <i class="fa fa-link" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <!-- <i class="fa fa-chain-broken" aria-hidden="true"></i> -->
            </a>
            Height <input type="text" name="custom-height" id="dataHeight"> PX
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="preset" data-toggle="buttons">
          <div id="standard" class="editor-section">
            <h2>Standard</h2>
            <div>
              <div>
                <label class="box btn active desktop" aria-pressed="true">
                  <input type="radio" class="sr-only" id="Desktop-ratio" name="aspectRatio" value="1.7777777777777777" data-option="{ &quot;width&quot;: 1920, &quot;height&quot;: 1080 }">
                  <p>
                  Desktop<br>
                  1920 x 1080
                  </p>
                </label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <label class="box btn laptop" aria-pressed="true">
                          <input type="radio" class="sr-only" id="Laptop-ratio" name="aspectRatio" value="1.6" data-option="{ &quot;width&quot;: 1440, &quot;height&quot;: 900 }">
                  <p>
                  Laptop<br>
                  1440 x 900
                  </p>
                </label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <label class="box btn thumbnail" aria-pressed="true">
                          <input type="radio" class="sr-only" id="Thumbnail-ratio" name="aspectRatio" value="1" data-option="{ &quot;width&quot;: 200, &quot;height&quot;: 200 }">
                  <p>
                  Thumbnail<br>
                  200 x 200
                  </p>
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="social" class="editor-section">
            <div class="section-header">
              <h2>Social networks</h2>
              <ul id="social-icons">
                <li class="fb"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                <li class="in"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                <li class="gplus"><i class="fa fa-google-plus-official" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                <li class="pn"><i class="fa fa-pinterest" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="social-boxes">
              <div id="fb" class="facebook active">
                <div class="box cover">
                  <label class="box btn cover" aria-pressed="true">
                    <input type="radio" class="sr-only" id="facbook-cover" name="aspectRatio" value="2.6285714286" data-option="{ &quot;width&quot;: 828, &quot;height&quot;: 315 }">
                    <p>
                    Facebook cover<br>
                    828 x 315
                    </p>
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="box profile">
                  <label class="box btn profile" aria-pressed="true">
                    <input type="radio" class="sr-only" id="facbook-cover" name="aspectRatio" value="2.6285714286" data-option="{ &quot;width&quot;: 828, &quot;height&quot;: 315 }">
                    <p>
                    Facebook profile<br>
                    180 x 180
                    </p>
                  </label>

                </div>
                <div class="box post">
                <label class="box btn post" aria-pressed="true">
                    <input type="radio" class="sr-only" id="facbook-cover" name="aspectRatio" value="2.6285714286" data-option="{ &quot;width&quot;: 828, &quot;height&quot;: 315 }">
                    <p>
                    Facebook post<br>
                    600 x 600
                    </p>
                  </label>

                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="in" class="linkedin">
                <div class="box cover">
                  <label class="box btn cover" aria-pressed="true">
                    <input type="radio" class="sr-only" id="facbook-cover" name="aspectRatio" value="2.6285714286" data-option="{ &quot;width&quot;: 828, &quot;height&quot;: 315 }">
                    <p>
                    linkedin cover<br>
                    828 x 315
                    </p>
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="box profile">
                  <label class="box btn profile" aria-pressed="true">
                    <input type="radio" class="sr-only" id="facbook-cover" name="aspectRatio" value="2.6285714286" data-option="{ &quot;width&quot;: 828, &quot;height&quot;: 315 }">
                    <p>
                    linkedin profile<br>
                    180 x 180
                    </p>
                  </label>

                </div>
                <div class="box post">
                <label class="box btn post" aria-pressed="true">
                    <input type="radio" class="sr-only" id="facbook-cover" name="aspectRatio" value="2.6285714286" data-option="{ &quot;width&quot;: 828, &quot;height&quot;: 315 }">
                    <p>
                    linkedin post<br>
                    600 x 600
                    </p>
                  </label>

                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="gplus" class="googlePlus">
                <div class="box cover">
                  <label class="box btn cover" aria-pressed="true">
                    <input type="radio" class="sr-only" id="facbook-cover" name="aspectRatio" value="2.6285714286" data-option="{ &quot;width&quot;: 828, &quot;height&quot;: 315 }">
                    <p>
                    Gplus cover<br>
                    828 x 315
                    </p>
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="box profile">
                  <label class="box btn profile" aria-pressed="true">
                    <input type="radio" class="sr-only" id="facbook-cover" name="aspectRatio" value="2.6285714286" data-option="{ &quot;width&quot;: 828, &quot;height&quot;: 315 }">
                    <p>
                    Gplus profile<br>
                    180 x 180
                    </p>
                  </label>

                </div>
                <div class="box post">
                <label class="box btn post" aria-pressed="true">
                    <input type="radio" class="sr-only" id="facbook-cover" name="aspectRatio" value="2.6285714286" data-option="{ &quot;width&quot;: 828, &quot;height&quot;: 315 }">
                    <p>
                    Gplus post<br>
                    600 x 600
                    </p>
                  </label>

                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="pn" class="pinterest">
                <div class="box cover">
                  <label class="box btn cover" aria-pressed="true">
                    <input type="radio" class="sr-only" id="facbook-cover" name="aspectRatio" value="2.6285714286" data-option="{ &quot;width&quot;: 828, &quot;height&quot;: 315 }">
                    <p>
                    pinterest cover<br>
                    828 x 315
                    </p>
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="box profile">
                  <label class="box btn profile" aria-pressed="true">
                    <input type="radio" class="sr-only" id="facbook-cover" name="aspectRatio" value="2.6285714286" data-option="{ &quot;width&quot;: 828, &quot;height&quot;: 315 }">
                    <p>
                    pinterest profile<br>
                    180 x 180
                    </p>
                  </label>

                </div>
                <div class="box post">
                <label class="box btn post" aria-pressed="true">
                    <input type="radio" class="sr-only" id="facbook-cover" name="aspectRatio" value="2.6285714286" data-option="{ &quot;width&quot;: 828, &quot;height&quot;: 315 }">
                    <p>
                    pinterest post<br>
                    600 x 600
                    </p>
                  </label>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="the-image">
        <div id="img-container">
          <img id="image" src="loading.gif" class="img-responsive" alt="Image to crop">
        </div>
        <div id="info">
          <p id="file-name"></p>
          <p id="file-size"></p>
        </div>
        <div id="download">
          <div id="image-format">
          <label class="btn active" aria-pressed="true">
            <input type="radio" id="download-jpg" name="fileType" value="image/jpeg" checked="checked">
            JPG
          </label>
          <label class="btn active" aria-pressed="true">
            <input type="radio" id="download-png" name="fileType" value="image/png">
            PNG
          </label>
          </div>
          <button id="prepareImage" class="btn btn-primary prepare-button" data-method="getCroppedCanvas" data-option="{ &quot;width&quot;: 1920, &quot;height&quot;: 1080 }">Download Image</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Show the cropped image in modal -->
        <div class="hidden" id="getCroppedCanvasModal" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="getCroppedCanvasTitle" tabindex="-1">
          <div class="modal-body"></div>
        </div><!-- /.modal -->
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
      <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified Cropper JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cropper.js"></script>
    <!-- Main javascript file -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**javascript - main.js**

```
window.onload = function () {

  'use strict';

  //set vars for common elements
  var Cropper = window.Cropper;
  var container = document.querySelector('#img-container');
  var prepareImage = document.getElementById('prepareImage');
  var actions = document.getElementById('editor');
  var download = document.getElementById('download');
  var dataHeight = document.getElementById('dataHeight');
  var dataWidth = document.getElementById('dataWidth');

  //prepare cropper options
  var options = {
    aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
    zoomable: false,
    checkCrossOrigin: true,
    ready: function (e) {
      console.log(e.type);
      },
    cropstart: function (e) {
      console.log(e.type, e.detail.action);
    },
    cropmove: function (e) {
      console.log(e.type, e.detail.action);
    },
    cropend: function (e) {
      console.log(e.type, e.detail.action);
    },
    crop: function (e) {
      var data = e.detail;
      console.log(e.type);
    },
    zoom: function (e) {
      console.log(e.type, e.detail.ratio);
    }
  };

  // prepare image
  var imageUrl = window.location.hash.substring(1);
  if (imageUrl !==""){
    var image = container.getElementsByTagName('img').item(0);
    image.src = imageUrl;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", imageUrl, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        cropper['replace'](imageUrl);
      }
    }
    xhr.send();
  }
  else{
    var image = container.getElementsByTagName('img').item(0);
  }
  image.onload = function(){
    var imageName = image.getAttribute('src');
    var imageWidth = image.naturalWidth;
    var imageHeight = image.naturalHeight;

    // preset info on page
    document.getElementById('file-name').innerHTML = imageName;
    document.getElementById('file-size').innerHTML = 'Original size: ' + imageWidth + 'x' + imageHeight;
    dataHeight.value = Math.round(imageHeight);
    dataWidth.value = Math.round(imageWidth);
  }

  //create cropper
  var cropper = new Cropper(image, options);

  var originalImageURL = image.src;

  //socail tabs
  actions.querySelector('#social-icons').onclick = function (event){
    var e = event || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if (target.type !== ''){
      var socialTarget = '#'+target.parentElement.className;
      var boxes = document.getElementById('social-boxes');
      $("#social-boxes >div.active").removeClass("active");
      boxes.querySelector(socialTarget).classList.add("active");
    }
  }

  // set image/cropper size
  actions.onchange = function (event) {
    var e = event || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    var isRadio;
    var isText;
    var data;
    var imageData;

    data = {
      method: target.getAttribute('data-method'),
      target: target.getAttribute('data-target'),
      option: target.getAttribute('data-option'),
      secondOption: target.getAttribute('data-second-option')
    };

    if (!cropper || (target.type === undefined)) {
      return;
    }

    if (target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'label') {
      target = target.querySelector('input');
    }

    isRadio = target.type === 'radio';
    isText = target.type === 'text';

    //set preset sizes
    if (isRadio) {
      options[target.name] = target.value;
      $('.box.btn.active').removeClass('active');
      $('#custom-sizes input').removeClass('active');
      target.parentNode.classList.add("active");
      prepareImage.setAttribute('data-option', data.option);
      options.ready = function () {
        console.log('ready');
      };
    }

    //set custom size
    if(isText){
      if (target.id === 'dataWidth'){
        dataHeight.value = Math.round(target.value * (image.naturalHeight/image.naturalWidth));
      }
      else if (target.id === 'dataHeight') {
        dataWidth.value = Math.round(target.value * (image.naturalWidth/image.naturalHeight));
      }
      $('.box.btn.active').removeClass('active');
      $('#custom-sizes input').addClass('active');
      prepareImage.setAttribute('data-option', '{ "width": '+dataWidth.value+', "height": '+dataHeight.value+' }');
      imageData = cropper['getImageData']();
      options['aspectRatio'] = imageData.aspectRatio;
      options['top'] = 0;
      options['left'] = 0;
      options['autoCropArea'] = 1;
    }

    // Restart
    cropper.destroy();
    cropper = new Cropper(image, options);
  };

  // set download button
  download.onclick = function (event) {
    var e = event || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    var result;
    var input;
    var data;
    var cropedImageName = "cropped.";
    var cropedImageType;

    if (!cropper) {
      return;
    }

    data = {
      method: target.getAttribute('data-method'),
      target: target.getAttribute('data-target'),
      option: target.getAttribute('data-option'),
      secondOption: target.getAttribute('data-second-option')
    };

    if (data.method === 'getCroppedCanvas') {
      data.option = JSON.parse(data.option);
      result = cropper[data.method](data.option, data.secondOption);
      if (result) {
        // prepare image and auto download

        // get filetype and set download name
        cropedImageType = $('input[name="fileType"]:checked').val();
        if (cropedImageType === 'image/jpeg'){
          cropedImageName = cropedImageName + 'jpg';
        }
        else{
          cropedImageName = cropedImageName + 'png';
        }

       //draw image
        //$('#getCroppedCanvasModal').find('.modal-body').html(result);

        // start auto download of image
        var a = $("<a>").attr("href", result.toDataURL(cropedImageType)).attr("download", cropedImageName).appendTo("body");
        a[0].click();
        a.remove();
      }
    }
  };

};
```

Hope this will help with the debug.
Thanks

Comment: You need to add exact steps to reproduce. I've tried your extension on a random web image and it worked without problems except it doesn't support WebP image format.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm for trying but i already solved it.
The issue was with cropper not being ready before seting the url, that's way it didn't worked on slower connections or big files i'm guessing, and worked after refresh (maybe from cache???)

Answer (score 0):

OK, found the issue.
When loading a new url for the cropper, we need to make sure he is ready:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        new Cropper(image, {
          ready: function () {
            cropper['replace'](imageUrl);
          }
        });
      }
}
```

and not just wait for the image request to load:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            cropper['replace'](imageUrl);
      }
    }
```

Hope it will help someone...